# unfortunately sqlite has stopped

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, activitynotfoundexception

i just got started with android and i'm trying to make a sign up page and save the input data in a sqlite database but i keep getting this error while compiling on my phone. "unfortunately sqlite has stopped";

signup class
package com.example.asus.sqlite;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText userinput ;
    private EditText passin;
    private EditText reppassin;
    private EditText emailin;
    private EditText phonenum;
    private Button   signup;
    public static String user     = "";
    public static String pass     = "";
    public static String reppass  = "";
    public static String phonen   = "";
    public static String mail     = "";


    UserInfo submit = new UserInfo();
    final DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);



        userinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userin);
        passin    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass1in);
        reppassin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass2in);
        emailin   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailin);
        phonenum  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phonein);
        signup    = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.signupbutt);
        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                user    = userinput.getText().toString().trim();
                pass    = passin.getText().toString().trim();
                reppass = reppassin.getText().toString().trim();
                phonen  = phonenum.getText().toString().trim();
                mail    = emailin.getText().toString().trim();

                if(pass.equals("") || user.equals("")  || reppass.equals("")  || phonen.equals("")  || mail.equals("")  ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "make sure to fill all the informations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else if(!pass.equals(reppass)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    submit.setUsername(user);
                    submit.setPassword(pass);
                    submit.setEmail(mail);
                    submit.setPhone(phonen);

                    handler.addUser(submit);
                    Intent redirect =  new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Signin.class);
                    startActivity(redirect);
                }


            }
        });




    }



}
```

databse class

package com.example.asus.sqlite;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

/**
 * Created by ASUS on 6/25/2017.
 */

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1 ;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sqliteApp.db" ;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user_infos";
    public static final String ID = "ID";
    public static final String USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String EMAIL = "Email";
    public static final String PHONE = "phonenum";




    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_NAME  + "("
                + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + USERNAME + " TEXT, "
                + PASSWORD + " TEXT, "
                + EMAIL + " TEXT, "
                + PHONE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        onCreate(db);


    }

    public void addUser(UserInfo submit) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(USERNAME, submit.getUsername()); // Contact Name
        values.put(PASSWORD, submit.getPassword()); // Contact password
        values.put(EMAIL, submit.getEmail()); // Contact password
        values.put(PHONE, submit.getPhone()); // Contact password

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    // Getting single contact
    public UserInfo getUser(String userName , String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_NAME, new String[] {
                        USERNAME, PASSWORD },  USERNAME + "=?" + " AND " + PASSWORD + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(userName) , String.valueOf(password) }, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        UserInfo user = new UserInfo (cursor.getString(0),
                cursor.getString(1),"","");
        // return contact
        return user;
    }




}
```

this is the logcat error

```
06-27 15:34:01.060 10546-10546/com.example.asus.sqlite E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.asus.sqlite, PID: 10546
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asus.sqlite/com.example.asus.sqlite.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.asus.sqlite/com.example.asus.sqlite.Signin}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2697)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                                          Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.asus.sqlite/com.example.asus.sqlite.Signin}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1791)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1513)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3940)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3888)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4211)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4179)
                                                                             at com.example.asus.sqlite.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6185)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200
```

Comment: Please paste you logtrace

Comment: Why does your Database class extends Activity?

Comment: i added the logcat

Comment: In addition to Ekalips comment.
It seems that you didn't declare your activity in your manifest. 
Can you please add your manifest?

Comment: `ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.asus.sqlite/com.example.asus.sqlite.Signin}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: What exactly in about "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml??" you did not fully understand?

Comment: Your Database class should extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` , not some activity. And you need to provide its constructor, override onCreate and onUpgrade as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is that you don't define an activity in manifest.xml file(Database **extends AppCompatActivity**). Okay, even if you'll do it you'll get an error, please tell us why your db class extending activity?

Comment: if i don't extend it android studio can't resolve the openOrCreateDatabase method i don't know why but i guess adding the acivity in manifest ll fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logcat error, you have to include the Signup Activity into your Android manifest file.

Comment: i did just the and android studio couldn't resolve the method openOrCreateDatabase